# Load-Balancing with ExpressionEngine

Tags: performance, aws, nginx

I am kind of new to loadbalancing. I've been tasked up with figuring out how to load balance our servers that run ExpressionEngine. We are using two plugins, Assets and CE_Image. I've been reading up online that it's not possible to have multiple servers running expressionengine. Firstly, is there a work-around on being able to have multiple expressionengine instances running on different servers? Secondly does anyone have experience with issues regarding to extensions while having multiple expressionengine systems running?

Our server is running on AWS and using nginx web server.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this one ExpressionEngine install, or multiple EE installs you want duplicated among multiple servers? I have a single install that sits on two app servers behind a load balancer and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: I'm trying with multiple EE installs. Are you using a file system?

Comment: @jrothafer, how do you sync the assets?

Comment: @RobsonSobral It's a hosting partner, but basically two VPS with their own environment but both pointing at a RAID array of SSDs for web root.

Comment: I guess you have one answer for this question, @jrothafer! ;-)